# How can I use unicode string as index for pd.DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unicode

I use Python 2.7 and I have created a pandas DataFrame using `pd.read_excel(my_path, encoding="utf-8")` named `my_reader`. One of its columns is named 'Descrição'.

I have all the columns names in a list named `client_list`.

When I'm trying to use my list's data as index for `my_reader` I get an error

```
KeyError: 'Descri\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o'
```

It works fine with all other data which contain only English letters. When I print `client_list` I get the names correctly displayed

```
print client_list[0]
Descrição
```

But

```
 client_list[0]
'Descri\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o'
```

So I can't use

```
my_reader[client_list[i]]
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list of column names is a list of `str` in the `utf-8` encoding. But the pandas columns have `unicode` strings as names, so the easiest solution is to "decode" your list of column names to `unicode` as well.

```
client_list = [ c.decode("utf8") for c in client_list ]
```

I can't see into your dataframe but I'll wager that *all columns*, not just the non-ascii ones, are `unicode` strings. The reason the other column names don't give you trouble is that Python 2 does a lot of implicit conversions behind the scenes (and `pandas` probably adds some of its own). With ascii strings the mapping between `str` and `unicode` is trivial, but with non-ascii things it is encoding-dependent. So just convert the entire list of names to unicode. Better yet, migrate all your text handling to unicode, as recommended for any application that sometimes deals with non-ascii data.

A better solution to your predicament would be to switch to Python 3. Its handling of non-ascii encodings is much more intuitive and robust-- you're likely to find that your code will "just work", just like it did for me under Python 3.

Comment: Yup, it's amazing how often that happens :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your dataframe is saved with `encoding="utf-8"`, when you use the `'Descri\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o'` as the index of the dataframe, better decode it with `"utf-8"`, then you can get the data. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
my_reader = pd.read_excel('comparison.xlsx',encoding="utf-8")
my_reader
```

`my_reader` will be:

```
    Col_1   Col_2   file    Descrição
0   Abc     Abk     cnl     DFSDF
1   Nck     Nck     Abk     DSFAF
2   xkl     cnl     Abc     FDAS
3   mzn     mzn     NaN     DFAS
```

You can use :

```
my_reader['Descrição'.decode('utf-8')]
```

This will give you the result:

```
0    DFSDF
1    DSFAF
2     FDAS
3     DFAS
Name: Descrição, dtype: object
```

For other column you also can trace with `unicode`:

```
my_reader['Col_2'.decode("utf-8")]
```

Output:

```
0    Abk 
1     Nck
2     cnl
3     mzn
Name: Col_2, dtype: object
```

Comment: All the other Columns should remain encoded. How can I decide when I need to decode?

Comment: it is ok even you decode it, you also can get the result.

Comment: this just decode it to `unicode`, and trace all the index with the `unicode`